# Setting the Javascript Mode for ServiceNow plugin in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, servicenow

So I am pretty much brand new to developing for ServiceNow, but not to being a developer, and I found that ServiceNow has an updated javascript Mode that allows ECMA2021/ES12+... I also discovered that I can work with it in VSCode, similar to how I am used to working with SalesForce and SFDC...

What I am looking for is the setting(s) I need to set so that that the ServiceNow extension will not kvetch about reserved words when trying to sync, like the following:

[image]

I have looked at the settings in the plugin, and I don't see what the setting to allow it to use teh updated setting in ServiceNow.

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to find this answer in the ServiceNow community pages:
https://www.servicenow.com/community/developer-forum/using-ecmascript21-in-vscode-creates-syntax-error/m-p/2381008/page/2

Gist of it is that you have to edit a specific portion of the extension file, located at `%userprofile%/.vscode/extensions/servicenow.now-vscode-1.5.0/out/extension.js`, from

```
u = new(0, r.CLIEngine)({
    envs: ["browser", "mocha"],
    useEslintrc: !1
});
```

to

```
u = new(0, r.CLIEngine)({
    envs: ["es2021","browser", "mocha"],
    useEslintrc: !1
});
```

The file is minified, so the easiest way to find it is to search for `r.CLIEngine`.

After that is done, make sure that `.eslinrc` file is pointed at the right ECMA level,

```
"env": {
    "es2021": true,
    "browser": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2021
  },
```

then open the command palette, and do a `Developer: Reload Window`.
After that, your ServiceNow sync will not throw the original error any more.